# TextView with multiple lines of text in a wrapping container - wrong height?

Tags: android

I found the following problem. Having something simple like this works:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="long text taking multiple lines ..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But if you have another component in the layout the TextView starts to behave weird. It seems to be one line short having text running out of the frame of the container:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="long text over multiple lines ..."/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bla"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post a screencap?

Comment: Try adding `android:baselineAligned="false"` to the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking if it was some sort of `PADDING` or `MARGIN` from the `LINEAR LAYOUT` or from the `TEXTVIEW` itself, looks like it's not.

But I was able to  align  it correctly by adding `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the `TEXTVIEW`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="long text over multiple lines ..."/>
```

Some values other than `center` works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

to require textview wrap down if string over with

Comment: Tried this but it does not help.